# Change the width and height of a swf dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, flash

I'm trying to use the following js to change the width and height of a swf.

```
$('object').attr({'width':100,'height':100});
$('object embed').attr({'width':100,'height':100});
```

The script works well on firefox, safari, IE8. However, it doesn't work on IE7.

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

How about with

```
$('object, embed')
    .attr({'width':100,'height':100})
    .width(100).height(100);
```

Comment: oh...the elements are not selected on IE7

Comment: but even if i try to get the <object> by id or class, it still cannot be selected
is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

How about wrap the Flash with a div. Set the Flash to 100% height and width. And then you resize the div instead?